# How to extract hierarchy of columns in a dimension table when there are two or more logical hierarchies?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I want to know what are the hierarchy columns in each dimension, and which are "higher" and "lower"? I have many dimensional tables but here is one that has multiple logical hierarchies.

The table and `limit 1` is as follows:

```
 manufacture_cal_key | manufacture_shift_code | manufacture_day_date | manufacture_date_shift | manufacture_yearmonth | manufacture_yearmonthday | manufacture_year | manufacture_yearquarter | manufacture_monthofyear | manufacture_quarterinyear
---------------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------
 mCAL_2017-05-10s04  | SH4                    | 2017-05-10 18:00:00  | mYMDS_2017_05_10_s4    | mYM201705             | mYMD20170510             | mY2017           | mYQ2017Q2               | mMO05                   | mQO2
(1 row)
```

As you can see, manufacture year can be a top-level column for manufacture_monthofyear and for manufacture_yearmonth? Or maybe I am wrong and don't understand hierarchies well enough.

I expect to know the hierarchies and if possible, some good references which can help me understand the first principles as well.

The table description is:
[image]

Comment: a true hierarchy table will have a uniqueID field and a parentID field(which is the uniqueID of the parent). See this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child) for more info

Comment: There is nothing special about hierarchies, and you should be free to create whatever you like based on your data, and multiple intersecting hierarchies are also logically fine. Where you will run into problems though is with many visualisation tools, cube builders, etc which will often want to uniquely find the parent from the child. In your example you cant do that with your monthofyear because there will be one mM05 for each year. So you would build Hierarchy on YearMonth, and add MOY as an atribute of the level.